# position of reflexive in a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verb, reflexive

Are both

> Ich kann es mir nicht leisten

> Ich kann mir es nicht leisten

correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are both grammatically correct, but this one

> Ich kann es mir nicht leisten.

is the much more common variant. This is because it follows the default order: pronoun accusative objects before dative objects. The alternative

> Ich kann mir es nicht leisten.

places *es* out of order and emphasises it too much in most situations. Please note that this default oder above does only apply to **pronoun** accusative objects. For **noun accusative objects** the default order is *after dative objects*. That's why it's

> Ich kann mir diese Wohnung nicht leisten.

and **not**

> <strike>Ich kann diese Wohnung mir nicht leisten.</strike>

(Actually, those are only rules of thumb. The real rule is *known information before new information* but you can hardly construct good sounding sentences with that one. As it's pretty hard to decide what is *known information* in the sense of German grammar.)

Comment: "Ich kann *es* mir nicht leisten", but "Ich kann mir *das* nicht leisten". It seemingly doesn't have to do so much with pronoun or noun, but with definite and indefinite, no?